# 404 Error connecting to Visual Studio Online, despite using a valid url

Tags: git, xamarin-studio, azure-devops

I am trying to get my Xamarin Studio IDE to connect to a Visual Studio Online Git Project Repository, but not having much luck.

I have tries the steps in [this](http://blog.falafel.com/using-visualstudio-com-s-online-git-repositories-to-host-your-xamarin-project/) guide, but it always throws a 404 error. I then tried not adding a user name or port number, as then the `url` generated at the top of the dialogue, gives a valid looking url, which when copied into a browser goes to the project page.

I have tried using `Alternative Credentials` as suggested in the post, however, I also tried using an access token, as this seems to have `succeeded` standard passwords. I tried these with both my Primary and Secondary User Names? 
Any Ideas how to get this working? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can get it work under my environment, quote my steps for your reference:

1. Launch Xamarin Studio and select "Version Control".
2. Select "Check Out".
3. Select "https" as the "Protocol" type on "Select Repository" dialog.
4. Open your VSO git project from browser.
5. Click "Code" and then click "Clone" button. (You should see a clone url after this)
6. Copy the clone url and paste it into "Url:" area of Xamarin "Select Repository" dialog.[image]
7. Click "OK" button.
8. Enter the alternative credentials in the prompted dialog.

Comment: So i can follow these steps and the checkout is completed successfully, but then as soon as I do a push, I get a credentials dialogue and when filled in, I get the error dialogue `Unexpected HTTP Error Code: 404` ? Is this an issue with my credentials being incorrect, because if I use incorrect details, I the credentials box pop up again, not the 404 code?

Comment: What credentials are you using when push? Alternative or Token? Can you check if your account has the permission to write the code from "Code\Security"? And also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using the Token Authentication and using OSX. Not sure about account permissions, couldn't find security under the code tab of the project site. I do however had admin privileges? and the token uses the all access option.

Comment: After open "Code" panel, you should see the repository list in the left panel, right click on it, you'll see "Security" option. And can you try to push the commits via git command?

Comment: I can use the repository when using Visual Studio on my Windows machine.  Not having much luck with the mac command line, although, I can clone successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The path in the example is no longer valid for Visual Studio Team Services. A valid path is "/_git/projectName".